# Appending List to List

Tags: java, object, append

I'm writing a class called `List` which creates an instance variable array of `Customers` (`Customer` is just another class that accepts `String` parameters for a person's name),

i.e `private Customer[] data`

I'm trying to write an append method that will take a `Customer` and add it to another `List` in the main method.

To do this, there seems to be a method called `addAll()`, but since I'm writing this code by scratch, I can't use this. I looked at the pseudo code though for this method to get a general idea and it converts the Object into an array and then uses `arraycopy` to append the two lists.

I meant to say, this way makes sense to me, if I were using `arrays`, but I'm trying to add a `Customer` object from another list and add them to a list in the main method.

Comment: If you're using an `arraycopy` then you must be using arrays (not `List`s). Please provide more context.

Comment: Sorry, I am using `List s`, I meant that I understand why the pseudo code uses `arraycopy`, but that I want to understand how to do it without, because I'm not using `arraycopy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of what you want, but I think you can implement the append method yourself just as what the `arraycopy` method do. Here is a simple example

```
class List {
    private int size;
    private Customer[] data;
    private final static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10; 

    public List() {
        size = 0;
        data = new Customer[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    public void append(List another) {
        int anotherSize = another.size;
        for (int i = anotherSize - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (size < data.length) {
                data[size++] = another.data[i];
                another.data[i] = null;
                another.size--;
            } else {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, the source code of `ArrayList` class is a good reference.

Comment: Thanks! Although I don't really get the lines `another.data[i] = null; another.size--;`, could you give a quick explanation?

Comment: @hello Those two lines are used to remove the element which have been taken and added to the base List. If you do not want to remove element as well as take it, you do not need to do that. Sorry for a mistake in the for loop, and I just fixed it.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense to remove the elements if you're starting from the end. Okay, thanks again!